# Active test networks

Tags: node, baking, protocol

There are many test networks on Tezos.

What are the active and soon to be active public ones?
How do we participate?
Are there accessible public nodes?

Comment: The most up-to-date resource on test network should be in the developer documentation: http://tezos.gitlab.io/introduction/test_networks.html

However, it doesn't answer all your questions so I'm leaving this as a comment in the hope that another user can provide more info.

Answer (score 0):

As commented above, https://tezos.gitlab.io/introduction/test_networks.html lists the current networks: mainnet, Edo2Net (mainnet test), Florencenet (next protocol, if it passes)

Every network is public and both test networks have free tokens from the faucet. You can participate by downloading/running the latest tezos software and using the `--network` flag to specify the network to which you want to connect.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely have a look at the [Teztnets](https://teztnets.xyz/). This framework has been developed to help everyone easily join testnets for Tezos. Having Docker pre-installed is enough and the simple commands of the website (depending on which testnet you which to take part in) will automatically let you join the effort.

Although, the link in the documentation is correct, this website actively keeps track of the current testnets and serves to automatically spawn daily and weekly testnets to challenge the latest codebase.